# Active Directory bulk import from csv file

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, bulk-import

I am trying to use the following code for bulk import in Active Directory into **All Customers** OU.

```
$Users = Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Path "C:\AnnexA.csv"
foreach ($User in $Users)
{
$Displayname = $User.Forenames + " " + $User.Surname
$UserFirstname = $User.Forenames
$UserLastname = $User.Surname
$OU = "OU=All Customers,DC=PentagonMoon,DC=local"
$SAM = $User.Forenames + "." + $User.Surname
$Town = $User.Town
$Street =$User.Address
$Postcode = $User.Postcode
$Telephone = $User.Telephone
$Email = $User.email

New-ADUser -Name $Displayname
-DisplayName $Displayname
-SamAccountName $SAM
-UserPrincipalName $UPN
-GivenName $UserFirstname
-Surname $UserLastname
-City $Town
-StreetAddress $Street
-PostalCode $Postcode
-HomePhone $Telephone
-EmailAddress $Email
-AccountPassword (ConverTo-SecureString - AsPlainText Password123 - Force)
-Enabled $true -Path "$OU"
-ChangePasswordAtLogon $false
-PasswordNeverExpires $true
}
```

The CSV file contains of Surname, Forenames, Address, Town, Postcode, Telephone, email titles.  I get a number of errors and cannot see what is wrong with the code.

Comment: It would help if you shared the errors you are seeing.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stackoverflow. 
You really need to google your question a lot before asking the question here.This task has been created thousands of times. 

No need to create new variables when the Import-CSV creates them for you. You just need to use `$_.Surname`.
Your Password will never work. You need to run that variable outside of the Foreach statement and give it a variable. 

You should check out this link and it will show you what you are doing wrong. 
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Create-Active-7e6a3978

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the only issue, but:

```
-AccountPassword (ConverTo-SecureString - AsPlainText Password123 - Force)
```

Should be

```
-AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText Password123 -Force)
```